# Communication from QML --> to Python --> back to QML

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyside2, pyside6

I am looking for the best way to communicate from QML to Python and then back to python again.
I am struggling to find the 'correct' way to do this as many resources briefly explain the topic but in different ways and seem to require large amounts of boiler plate code.

For context I am currently using PySide2.

This is the kind of workflow that I am looking to use this in:

QML on button click send input to python --> receive in python --> do some processing on this input --> pass back to QML.

Please provide the best way to do this and with as much explanation as possible, thanks!